# Easiest way how to modify the source of a library from Maven

Tags: java, maven, opensaml

I am experimenting with a SAML library OpenSAML https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OS30/overview. The library is distributed using Maven through the repository https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/org/opensaml/.
My pom.xml looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xyz.test.ho</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyzs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <opensaml.version>3.2.0</opensaml.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-messaging-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-messaging-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-soap-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${opensaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>shib-release</id>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Since the repository also contains javadoc + sources, is it somehow possible to modify the source code of different files in the libraries? I am using IntelliJ IDEA and it does not let me edit the source code. I have googled a bit and most people suggest getting the source code from the repository and compiling my own jar. This does not seem that easy since the documentation for this library is basically non existent and it is composed of multiple sub-libraries.

I was able to create modules in my IntelliJ IDEA project from the source codes for different library parts but then the issue is with the dependencies.

I just do not understand why cannot the IDE rebuild the library since it knows all the dependencies and source codes. Is there really no easier way?

Comment: "*I just do not understand why cannot the IDE rebuild the library since it knows all the dependencies and source codes*" Because it doesn't know how to build it. Maybe it needs a specific compiler version, maybe it needs aspectj instrumentation, maybe it needs lombok, whatever. Having some source is not necessarily enough. In theory, the feature you're asking for could exist for some projects with a basic build process. I'm not sure it would be very useful, which is probably why it doesn't exist. You can implement an  IntelliJ plugin to do it if you really want to.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read that: `End of Life Warning`...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not easier way.

You should avoid to change code of third-party libraries. Only in very rare cases this is a good idea.

Instead, you can write some kind of wrapper around the library to solve your issue.